# How to single out a sound

Tags: sound-design, music, synthesizer

I have a track that I made with a synth patch that I've lost and am unable to recreate by ear. I read somewhere that it is possible to single out a sound if you have one track with the sound and one track without it, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the phase of the track without your target sound and then mix both to mono. This will subtract the unwanted sound from the overall mix and should leave you with the sound you want. This is all of course assuming that both tracks are phase-coherent and sampled aligned.

Comment: Thank you so much, any tips to clean the sound even further?

Comment: Only that you may need to tune the level of the inverted track to get the maximum attenuation - that's about as much as you can do in this situation though.